# How do I get 2 separate displays of a view in one page that are displaying contents from two different content types?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, panels, views

For example, I have a Page view which displays Content Type A Title, Post date and categories. This page will lists out all of the matching contents that this user has published.

Then I created a Block view that displays contents from Content Type B with Title and categories. The similarity between content type A and B is the categories. I want to display the contents of the block under each result in the Page that matches each category chosen for that node.

How would you display this in the view? I have heard of [Views Attach](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_attach) or [Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) . But the first one is only for D6 while second will probably not work since I'm not using entities ... or am I?

Or can this be done using Panels? How to do this dynamically with the Block view auto populating the Page view with the right amount of results?

I want to be able to display multiple views results for multiple taxonomies in one page. The content types do not have references for each other. But they do share the same taxonomy vocabulary and its terms.

Edit: This is how I want to display the entire page

```
Page Results Name 

Page Result 1: Title    Date Posted     Categories
    Block Result 1 Title     Matching Categories

Page Result 2: Title    Date Posted     Categories
    Block Result 2 Title     Matching Categories

Page Result 3: Title    Date Posted     Categories
    Block Result 3 Title     Matching Categories

...
```

The Page is populated by Content Type A
The Block is populated by Content Type B

Want Each Block to have 10+ results that matches categories on Content Type A

It's not just placing Block view underneath the Page view. They're embedded together.

Right now, I have the 2 views displaying the correct results separately. But having trouble integrating them together.

Oh and the results for Content Type A should only display contents that the logged in user published. But the Content Type B can be from any author as long as it matches the Categories.

Comment: Hello and welcome. "The best" encourages opinion-based answers, and that's what we want to avoid here. Consider either defining what qualities you want, or simply asking how to do it, and seeing what people answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of Taxonomy, Views & Panels.

1. Add the same taxonomy vocabularies to both the Content types A & B
2. Create a view for Content type A with Contextual filter for Term-ID
3. Repeat the same for Content type B
4. Override the Panels page for Taxonomy & create the variant for your vocabulary
5. Add the above 2 views on the created Panels variant & also pass the argument term id to the view.

Well, you will have to dig into the Panels to get your requirement implemented.

Comment: Will try this suggestion. Panels is too complicated to understand, but I think it might be the only way to get this showing correctly. Will probably ask more questions later.

Comment: Well, Panels are fun once you get hold of them. I have given you another approach as well. Anyways, check this video tutorial by Shane Thomas (You should check his videos. Those have helped me over time, here & there).  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VIkE2ZS5oU

This video demonstrates the overiding of a Node (content type page). You, in your case will have to use "Term-Page" in Panels. Its tricky, but not tough.
Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks amohite88. Will check out that video tutorial. Appreciate it.

Comment: I semi got this working from your Panels suggestion by adding the Block view results in the Panels content Type A page display. Problem is that some results for Content Type B is getting displayed multiple times because the taxonomies exist more than once for each result. Is there a way to only display one of each result for Content Type B? ... if you're wondering the long break from previous question is because waiting for design.

Comment: Restricting item of a view output...??  You can always restrict that using the no. of items to display under the PAGER settings.

Comment: To reduce duplicates you can use the OTHER settings section > Query Settings > Distinct.

Comment: When I added the SQL Distinct, it doesn't really reduce duplicates because each content type B has more than one matching category from content type A. Still a problem. Besides that, the Content type B is displaying correctly on the node panel page itself. I may be doing something wrong with either the Views or Panels setup for the main Dashboard page that lists out all of the nodes. On the Views Format, do you use Rendered entity on Show Display and Full content? Because when I did that, the full content default is displaying, but not the panels display. What am I missing?

Comment: With more searching, I was able to find [Views Distinct] (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) to remove repeats of title. But the views full node still isn't rendering the node panel view display. Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed reply. 
Could you look into this - https://www.drupal.org/node/1422454

This might help in what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If You are not comfortable with Panels, then

1. Create one of the required views, a view page (for Content-type A) with proper contextual filters.
2. Create the other view (Content-type B) as an attachment (attachment Views).

   - Select INHERIT contextual filters while creating it.
   - Basically, both the views should have the same contextual filters.
3. Attach it to the first view created for Content-type A.

This might be an alternate solution.

For overriding the default taxonomy term paths check this tutorial -
[Overriding the default taxonomy page with a view in Drupal 7](http://www.webbykat.com/2012/04/overriding-default-taxonomy-page-view-drupal-7)

- Hope you are able to manipulate the contextual filters properly in the views.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have the contextual filter set correctly and both views show the correct data, you can do this without using any additional modules - include the block view as a footer to the first view - or under admin/structure/blocks you can assign the block view to only appear in the content area on the page address for the first view.

Comment: It's not that simple. I want the block display to embed for each result in the Page View.

Comment: Oh I see, that wasn't clear in the original question